# Save data into ArrayList of other class

Tags: java

I have a class where I define an array list and a getter method for the array list:

```
private ArrayList<Double> abc = new ArrayList<Double>();

public void setAbc(ArrayList<Double> abc) {
    this.abc = abc;
}
```

In another class I try to save data into this array list with a method:

```
private void test() {

    ABCclass x = new ABCclass();

    ArrayList<ABCclass> list = new ArrayList<ABCclass>();
    ArrayList.add(3.14);
    ArrayList.add(5.22);

    x.setAbc(list);
}
```

Whenever I try to do this, I get prompted with:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Thank you for brevity but the class definitions would be helpful

Comment: Surely this fails to compile with the message `non-static method add(E) cannot be referenced from a static context`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayList.add(3.14);` should be `list.add(3.14)` as that is the name you gave the variable initialized in the line before (i.e. `ArrayList<ABCclass> list = new ArrayList<ABCclass>();`)